# Segfault with C function notify_notification_update()

Tags: c, lua, gtk, libnotify

Simply enough, I'm having an issue where I'm getting a segfault when calling a libnotify function. Erroring code:

```
int lua_libnotify_new(lua_State *L) {
    const char *summary = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    const char *body = lua_isstring(L, 2) ? lua_tostring(L, 2) : NULL;
    const char *icon = lua_isstring(L, 3) ? lua_tostring(L, 3) : NULL;
    NotifyNotification *notification = (NotifyNotification *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(NotifyNotification));
    /* Error is the below line */
    notify_notification_update(notification, summary, body, icon);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the error. Exactly where it's getting segfault.

Comment: .CORE?  you have .core dump ? Use gdb to debug.

Comment: You should probably check that all 4 of those pointers are non-NULL, unless the documentation for `notify_notification_update` specifically says its arguments are allowed to be NULL.

Comment: Startup - It's only saying it's segfaulting.

Comment: http://sprunge.us/RCPI There is the core dump, Ramy.

Comment: Nate - The last two can be NULL, luaL_checkstring breaks the function execution if there's no string on the Lua stack, and `notification` is something but I don't know enough about `lua_newuserdata` to tell you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I realized that it should've been sizeof(NotifyNotification*). Resolved.